# Разделить массив Php

Tags: php

Есть код

```
    $a = explode("\r\n", $_POST["tel"]);
    foreach ( $a as $num ) {
    $operator = substr($a[0],1,3); 
}
```

Получаем номера списком. Ну почему массив получается склеиным? 
Вводим в форме:
89896378145
89896377767
89896376568

Если вывести $operator, то получим 989989989. А мне нужно разделить 989 между собой. Как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно записать каждое значение в массив:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $operator[] = substr($value, 1, 3);
}
```

Либо в строку, разделенную пробелом (или любым другим символом, на ваше усмотрение):

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $operator .= substr($value, 1, 3) . ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$operator**[]** = substr($a[0],1,3);